# vlookup sum to calculate total hours assigned next to dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm attempting to calculate a total number of hours based on entering 2 different dates. Each day between the dates has assigned 'hours worked'.

I'm trying to use `Sumproduct` or `Arrayformula` and `Sumif`,  not having luck with either as of just yet... Any help appreciated :)

[image: sum from lookup table]

[image: SumIf]

As far as i've got is selecting 2 dates and adding them together. Not everything inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY({A9:B}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1>=date'"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col1<=date'"&TEXT(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thankyou user0, works perfect!