# Using Vlookup with Dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, vlookup

Here's the set up to the problem I'm having.

I have a column of dates and a column of truck numbers. I'm trying to use `VLOOKUP` to find what truck numbers correspond to the dates. There are multiple dates and they're in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format. A date will have multiple truck numbers attached to it. I've attached a picture of the data I'm wanting to use.

My question is how would I go about using VLOOKUP with the dates in column B as the search criteria? What I have so far is: `=VLOOKUP("3/24/2021", B:E, 4, 0)`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formula, `=VLOOKUP("3/24/2021", B:E, 4, 0)`, for Google Sheets the first parameter is a text value, not a date. Instead of `"3/24/2021"` you could use `DATE(2021,3,24)`, by the other hand, `VLOOKUP` will return only the first match. If you want all the the Trucks numbers for a certain date instead of VLOOKUP use `FILTER` or `QUERY`.

NOTE: To return a date value instead of `DATE` you might also use `TO_DATE`. For details look at the function helper is shown when typing functions in a formula.

Related

- [vlookup sum to calculate total hours assigned next to dates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/126533/88163)
- [Google Sheets VLookup Help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154776/88163)

Comment: Thanks! I used QUERY like you suggested and it's much better suited for my needs!